# How do I turn a single app into two separate flavors?

Tags: android, gradle, android-flavors

I have a single app that I need to split into two flavors. The app functionality is a lot like Uber (not for driving though), in that there will be a client app that handles all of the ride requests and a "driver" app that alerts them to client requests(continuing with the Uber example). So far I have completed the client app, and I was hoping to reuse the code to create the "driver" app.

My issue is that I don't really know how I should approach this task when it comes to packages and whatnot. I already have the flavor root folders set up, but should I simply copy and paste? Is there a better way?

I've been debating simply creating an entirely new app, but it would be preferential to keep the same auth codes and sha for Google sign-in purposes.

Comment: Actually there is no really a correct answere to your questions its upto your taste on how you handle things, either build modules or use flavors. The best way to guide you is to build a **Use case diagram**. [Here](http://epf.eclipse.org/wikis/openup/core.tech.common.extend_supp/guidances/concepts/resources/atm_uc_diagram.gif) is what it looks like.

Comment: one way is that you can separate out the client and the driver functionality individually and allow access them by using login functionality  and give then rights accordingly. Prepare a flow and divide the functionality based on the client and driver, think of the features you will allow to access both with the use of same code.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to add a separate Manifest to the flavor? I need one for each flavor because one flavor will have a few different activities. If I try to use only one in main, it can't find the path to the non-used activities.